# C++ ignore a variable and prevent output

Tags: c++

I have 2 variables one has a value of 5 the other has a value of 0. if i have:

```
cout << var1;      //the one with a value of 5
cout << var2;      //the one with a value of 0
```

is there a way to make the second variable not print anything if its value is 0 at that point in the code?

Comment: You need to read a good C++ book,Contrary to what most new users don't think of,reading a good book is the best way to learn C++.This is pretty much basic and any good book should help you understand this,Unless I am misunderstanding your Q.

Answer (score 5):

Just use an if-statement:

```
cout << var1;
if (var2 != 0)
     cout << var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be this operator [(bool) ? (iftrue) : (iffalse)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation);

```
std::cout << (var2 == 0) ? "" : var2;
```

This solution enables you to add more output after var2 even though var2 shall not be printed:

```
std::cout << (var2 == 0) ? "" : var2 << " i am after var2 in any case" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Except that won't compile; `""` and `var2` have incompatible types.